# How to get View's X coordinate when View is positioned with margins?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-xml

I've inserted an `ImageView` via Activity's main XML file. It is aligned with parents top left corner, but top and left margins are set to `16dp`. 
I drag this view around the screen and animate it to initial position when released.

How could I find initial X value without hardcoding it? After converting dp pixels to simple pixels correct value is 42 px. If I call method `myImageView.getX()` it returns `0.0`.

Comment: I can find margin value by reading it from `MarginLayoutParams`, but is there a way to read X?

Answer (score 1):

Try to get position by

```
    Rect targetRect = new Rect();
    myImageView.getLocalVisibleRect(targetRect);

    int x = myImageView.getTop());
    int y = myImageView.getLeft();
```

Comment: I dont understand why, but it also returns zero values. I also tried other Rect retrieving methods (global, drawing...)

Comment: Where are you trying to get coords? maybe layout is not calculated sizes yet. Try OnWindowFocusChanged callback https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onWindowFocusChanged%28boolean%29

Comment: Initially I tried it at the end of `onCreate`, but now also tried in `onWindowFocusChanged()` - it still returns zero, but it does return correct value when using `getLeft()` and also it returns correct value when using `getGlobalVisibleRect()`. Thanks for the pointer. I dont know whom to assign correct answer, as both are partially correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the position of a `view` relative to his parent with `getLeft()` and `getTop()`.

From the google developer docs:

> It is possible to retrieve the location of a view by invoking the
>   methods getLeft() and getTop(). The former returns the left, or X,
>   coordinate of the rectangle representing the view. The latter returns
>   the top, or Y, coordinate of the rectangle representing the view.
>   These methods both return the location of the view relative to its
>   parent. For instance, when getLeft() returns 20, that means the view
>   is located 20 pixels to the right of the left edge of its direct
>   parent.

This means you can get x with the following code snippet:

```
int x = imageView.getLeft();
```

Comment: `getLeft()` also returns zero, same as `getX()`

Comment: But this method works when used in `onWindowFocusChanged()`